# Cauchy's theorem for a convex

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that there is a theorem that says that if $U $ is a convex open subset of $\mathbb{C} $ and $f $ is a holomorphic function on $U $ then $\int\limits_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$ for any closed path $\gamma$ in $U $.

But what if this closed path was the boundary of $U $, we can not say that it is still a closed path in $U $, but is the integral of f over the boundary of $U $ still zero.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This seems quite related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518709/extension-of-cauchy-integral-formula

Comment: If $U$ is an arbitrary convex open set there is a problem in defining intergral over boundary of $U$.

Comment: Well, if $U$ can be extended to contain that border, yes. However, $f$ might contain poles on the border. Take for example $f(z) =1/z$ with $U$ the open unit square in the first quadrant.

Comment: The boundary curve need not be differentiable everywhere (differentiability could fail on a Cantor set), so you would need care in defining and integral $dz$ there.

Comment: More than the presence of poles on the boundary, there are holomorphic functions defined on eg the unit disk that cannot be extended continuously at any point of the unit circle